# c# WINFORM file asscociation issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have WinForm application which is almost ready to go for production and here is the problem that I am facing and I am not able to resolve it.

Secondly sorry to post an image of the error log instead of actual text for that.

I am sort of new user of stack overflow and could not fix the formatting issue at all.

File Test.DAT is associated with KT.exe. But upon trying to open Test.DAT using KT.exe an  exception is thrown. 
    (please see attached image...again sorry for the image).

I created a sample windows application which works fine but this one does not.

So, I am totally confused about what's wrong with it?

So, now back to the problem. Look at the following file structure:

```
C:\PTS\KT\KT.ext
C:\PTS\KT\log4.net
C:\PTS\KT\Workspace\test.DAT
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

SOLUTION:  Sorry for raising false alarm. Actually to get assembly information I was loading KT.exe inside Main() using Assembly.LoadForm("KT.exe") which was throwing error. I updated the code to Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); I can't believe that it took so long to figure out this.

[image: Error log]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What's the difference between the simple application that does work and the one that generated that output?

Comment: There's at least one / too many in that exception message.

Comment: the file structure is same both. The only difference is actual application has more dlls included than sample application.

Comment: SOLUTION: Actually to get assembly information I was loading KT.exe inside Main() using Assembly.LoadForm() which was throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the file association does not include the full path to kt.exe, only the file name. So when you open the file in the Workspace dir, the operating system tries to find kt.exe there as well.

You can test this by moving the .dat file from workspace into the same directory as kt.exe, then double-click on it.

**Update:**

To re-associate the file with your program, take the following steps:

1) Open a command prompt

2) Clear the existing association by entering:

```
ASSOC .dat=
```

3) Create a new file type entry for your app by entering:

```
FTYPE KTDatFile="c:\pts\kt\kt.exe" %1 %*
```

4) Associate the new file type with your extension by entering:

```
ASSOC .dat=KTDatFile
```

Comment: You are right. If I will try opening .dat file where the .exe file is then it works. The file association is done using windows so how can I control the full path/file name?

Comment: The easiest way, if it is on just one machine, is right-click on the .Dat file, select the Open With menu, then the Choose default program... option. Browse to the kt.exe file using the Browse... button and make sure that the Always use the selected program to open this kind of file flag is checked. These instructions will vary slightly based on the OS you are using, but should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: that is what exactly I had done and I end up getting this issue.

Comment: ok, updated the answer with details on how to disassociate and reassociate.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried your approach and re associated the file but no luck yet.

Comment: Although I found the problem in my coding. Thanks for your help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to load the "KT.exe" from the Workspace directory but you have it in the parent directory to Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Sorry for raising false alarm. Actually to get assembly information I was loading KT.exe inside Main() using Assembly.LoadForm("KT.exe") which was throwing error. I updated the code to Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); I can't believe that it took so long to figure out this.